# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import vk
session=vk.Session("token")
vkapi = vk.API(session)
n = vkapi.friends.get(order='hints',fields='can_write_private_message',count=10)
z = []
for i in range(len(n)):
    if n[i].get('can_write_private_message')==1:
        z[i]['uid']=n[i]['uid']
        z[i]['name']=n[i]['first_name']
    else:
        pass
print(z)
```

Почему вылетает `IndexError: list index out of range` на 8 строчке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас список `z` изначально пустой (длина равна 0), а в цикле вы в него пытаетесь что-то записать, отсюда ошибка. Т.е. у вас i меняется от 0 до длины списка n (-1), вы пытаетесь писать по элементам z с такими индексами, но таких элементов в списке z нет.

Чтобы работало как вам нужно, нужно сначала заполнить список z пустыми словарями, чтобы он стал такой же длины как список n. В данном случае заполнять нужно словарями, т.к. к элементам вы обращаетесь через строковые индексы `['uid']` и `['name']`, значит каждым элементом списка должен быть словарь.

```
...
n = vkapi.friends.get(order='hints',fields='can_write_private_message',count=10)
z = [dict() for _ in range(len(n))]
for i in range(len(n)):
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло